# Get position of url with image

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the position of url with img from text.

I'm trying it :

```
var text ="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPFuhbEhsy0 https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

var imgRegexp = /(https?:\/\/.*\.(png|jpg))/
var imgFind = text.search(imgRegexp);

alert(imgFind);
```

it returns to me a 0, when i want the position of the second url.

Comment: Is that url a real example scenario?

Comment: the urls are random, I need get the position of the first url with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your regex is matching from first `http://` to last `.png`.

You will need to use `negative lookahead` for correct search:

```
var imgFind = text.search(/https?:\/\/(?!.*?https?:\/\/).*?\.(png|jpg)/);
// 43
```

Here `(?!.*?https?:\/\/)` makes sure that only closes `https?://` is matched from `.png or .jpg`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the regular expression as follows:

```
var text ="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPFuhbEhsy0 https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

var imgRegexp = /(https?:\/\/[\S]+\.(png|jpg))/
var imgFind = text.search(imgRegexp);

alert(imgFind);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a negative lookahead, like this:

```
var regex=new RegExp(/https?:\/\/(?!.*?https?:\/\/).*?\.(png|jpg)/); 
var imgFind=text.search(regex);
```